# How to solve some simple integrals (HW)

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'm stuck with those integrals. Can you give me a hint how to start solving?

$$\int{\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1}}dx$$

$$\int{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** try the substitution $u=\log(x+1)$

**Hint:** use partial fractions to write $\dfrac1{x^2-1}=\dfrac A{x-1}+\dfrac B{x+1}$

Comment: I am reminded of [Goldilocks and the Three Bears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_the_Three_Bears) for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

$\bullet (\displaystyle \ln (x+1))'=\frac{1}{x+1}$

$\bullet \displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1/2}{x-1}-\frac{1/2}{x+1}$

Comment: This porridge is too hot (+1)

Comment: @robjohn Agreed, but I couldn't just edit my answer and copy yours, that's why I kept it like this.But I wouldn't change the first hint.

Comment: @robjohn I got it.

Comment: [Good](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM1VXhZT37E)

Answer (score 1):

For the first integral, use $u$-substitution.

For the second integral, use partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: This porridge is too cold (+1)